# TypeScript & SystemJS: angular ui router module not registered in transpiled js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I'm writing an `AngularJS` app, with `TypeScript` as a transpiler and `SystemJS` for module loading. I'm trying to load the `angular-ui-router` module to configure the routing, but fail to do so. I get this error:

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

This is the script:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
import * as router from "angular-ui-router";

const app: angular.IModule = angular.module("my.website", ["ui.router"]);
app.config((stateProvider: router.IStateProvider) => {
    ...
});
```

This is how the script is transpiled:

```
System.register(["angular"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
...
```

As you can see, the **angular-ui-router is not registered**, and hence the module is not loaded. Why? What am I doing wrong?

For completeness:
this is the SystemJS config:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        "angular": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js",
        "angular-ui-router": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"
    }
});
```

These are the relevant TypeScript settings:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "system"
```

I have loaded the TypeScript definition files using `typings`.

Transpilation is done by `gulp-typescript`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by importing both the file and the module. Ugly as it may be, this works:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
import "angular-ui-router";
import * as router from "angular-ui-router";

const app: angular.IModule = angular.module("my.website", ["ui.router"]);
app.config((stateProvider: router.IStateProvider) => {
    ...
});
```